# securing PHP page with GET var

Tags: php, security

I have a page that I want to execute via cron. It just does some pretty simple archiving stuff, nothing super high-security, no DB access etc.

Is it a secure practice to simply require a GET var to be present in order to execute the page? So `myarchiver.php` would be something like:

```
<?php

$mysecret_word = "abc123";

if ($_GET['secret'] == $mysecret_word){
    // execute my stuff here
}
```

Then you'd just call `myarchiver.php?secret=abc123` in the crontab and the process would run, while any wrong answer or attempt to execute the page with no secret would simply present a blank page (with no extra server load).

I realize this is not "secure" against man in the middle attacks and if the site was compromised-- but I believe in general it's plenty secure to keep this script from being fired by random script kiddies and other idiots who may somehow know about its existence? The thing I'm guarding against is random malicious users who may know about this script bombarding it with requests in order to dos/tie up resources.

EDIT TO ADD: the server is not accessible via SSH and the cron is being executed on a remote machine-- so it must be done via an http request.

Thanks for input.

Comment: That's a good solution if external script access is needed, but in your case I would just place the script outside of the webroot.

Comment: @zzzzBov-- care to elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, why not just check the IP address of the server making the request?

If it has to be done via an HTTP request and simply checking the IP address isn't an option, you can have your cron run a script similar to "runcron.php". That script would in turn make a CURL or WGET request to the actual cron script you want to run.

That would allow you to pass a dynamic **hash** instead of a static key. That would prevent someone from just repeating the HTTP request if they happen to sniff the traffic. For the hash you could use anything dynamic like the date combined with a salt.

Example:

```
if (md5('secretword') . date('H')) == $_GET['hash']) { // do cron }
```

That would at least rotate your key once an hour.

Comment: thanks! that's the best advice yet. I like the idea of a rotating secret, and you're also right about restricting based on IP, though I suppose that could be spoofed too. However, for a pretty low-security system like this with nothing critical to be exploited, I think your idea will work just fine.

Answer (score 4):

If this script is never going to be run from the browser, you should place the file outside of your web root directory where browsers cannot reach it and just have your cron run the script at the alternate location. It would definitely be the most secure way to do it.

If you're on a shared hosting environment, you may need browser access for manual running. I would just use SSH to manually run the file from its location since it only takes me a couple seconds to login to SSH and get to the directory. Personally, I just prefer not to have excess pages laying around on my website.

Comment: @animuson-- you're totally right, and I should have stipulated that this would be a remotely fired cron job, and I can't rely on SSH, or I'd do that too. Thanks for the input.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by what you mean that it's remotely executed. A normal cron job is automatically run at a set interval of time which would not require remote access.

Comment: the process to be executed is on a remote server, over which I have limited control. So from my "control" server I want to be sure a backup/archive job is being run to ensure data is set. I know rsync etc. would be preferred, but as I said, I don't control the remote environment. So I'll crontab a wget to hit this php page that will perform the archiving for me.

Comment: I see, well if you really need to do it this way, then you should at least you SSL so that the 'password' cannot be intercepted by others. I would try to figure out a way to simply run the cron job on the physical server though.

Comment: understood-- but the question really isn't "what's the best way to do this" the question is "is this way relatively secure"-- thanks again for taking the time to respond.

Comment: It would be more secure if you used SSL. Without SSL, bad people can see your request and intercept it, and the password you use to run the script is right there in the URL. At least this way you have a better chance of people not running your script with the password over and over wasting your resources, even if they may be minute.

Comment: right-- hence I noted that I realized that this was subject to man in the middle hacks. But I do think this is a pretty remote possibility.

Answer (score 0):

Also, crontab won't let you pass GET variables. You'll have to do this -

```
/usr/bin/php /home/blah.php hello
```

Then in the script -

```
$argv = $_SERVER['argv'];
echo $argv[1];
```

Someone correct me if I'm mistaken.

Comment: you could fire a wget request via cron

Answer (score 0):

This is a technique that facebook uses on their logout.php file, so that if someone sends a link to logout.php it won't log them out. I would recommend doing this.

Answer (score 0):

```
$mysecret_word = "abc123";

if ($_GET['asd2edxc32cwqcxad'] === $mysecret_word){
    // execute my stuff here
} else {
  error_log('oopis');
  header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
  die();
}
```